# C# Issue WebBrowserReadyState - knowing when page has refreshed

Tags: page-refresh

I hope this isn't a stupid question. However I am writing a program at the moment which is a front end for a website booking system. 
When I navigate to a specific link it remembers previous information on the page - So I have to make it load the page and then refresh - It's a bit messy doing this, so I have created another form which comes up during the loading called pleasew.cs. It will show "pleasew" for the first while loop and then I am assuming that "WebBrowserReadyState" is set to "Complete." and it more or less then closes the "pleasew" form before it's completed the refresh. Is there anything I can do to reset "WebBrowserReadyState" before it refreshes? Or is there another solution at all?

Many Thanks for looking

Here is the code:

```
    private void button7_Click_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        webBrowser1.Navigate("www.test.co.uk");
        pleasew pleasewait = new pleasew();
        pleasewait.Show();

        while (webBrowser1.ReadyState != WebBrowserReadyState.Complete)
        {
            Application.DoEvents();

        }

        webBrowser1.Refresh();

        while (webBrowser1.ReadyState != WebBrowserReadyState.Complete)
        {
            Application.DoEvents();

        }
        pleasewait.Hide();

    }
```

Comment: I'm not at all sure what you're trying to accomplish here ... but have you tried using "Sessions"?    http://asp.net-tutorials.com/state/sessions/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand your problem right, you beleive the readystate doesn't get out of complete status when you do your refresh.  Have you debugged to be certain it never enters the second while loop?  Maybe because it's a refresh, it loads up from the cache, and that's the source of your confusion.

Try doing a second Navigate instead of Refresh and see what happens.

Comment: Sorry about the late reply. The issue is the link is basically an online booking system and this link takes you directly to the workshops themselves. You can see how many people are booked on each workshop. If I say, add myself onto a workshop and then click back on the workshop link it won't register that I have been added to the workshop until I refresh the page. So I cannot re-navigate to the page. Navigating to the page and refreshing looks messy I have tried to use the "WbReadyState" twice to start and stop a form which says "Loading Please wait"
Sorry I am a newbie when it comes to C#

Comment: Without knowing more about the booking system and workshops you mentioned, it's hard to say, but I'd be inclined to think there'd be another way of going about this.  It sounds interesting.